# How to fix LFO sync by changing component values

Tags: oscillator, synthesizer

I've built an LFO with a sync output for a modular synth project.

The LFO circuit is based on http://www.electro-music.com/forum/topic-31166.html and the reset part I added into that one using https://www.facebook.com/176989513877/photos/a.10150261457078878.340231.176989513877/10151593786478878/?type=1&theater

So my complete circuit looks like this:

[image]

Problem I think I have is that the order of magnitudes for the sync part and the actual LFO, in particular the timing cap - is way off. Thereforethe short timing pulse generated by the sync circuit doesn't seem to be enough to entirely reset the LFO timing cap. This is a scope readout where I'm trying to sync the LFO (triangle) from another LFO (square):

[image]

Obviously syncing is going on, but it seems to signal is to short to entirely reset the LFO.

So I'm pondering about the best way to fix this. I'm really new to this but my best guess is to decrease R6 a lot, but I'm a bit  afraid about what will happen then with relation to R7 and the JFET. I would need to decrease it a lot I think if I'm to hope it to be enought to fully reset the cap.

Another idea is to try to extend the pulse, but at this point I'm not even sure if it's C1 or D1 that really sets the limit there. I'm guessing I could increase the value of C1 to make the pulse longer?

What's the best option here?

Update ---
Changed C1 from 1nF to 15nF but it hardly got better, rather it started syncing on downs as well as ups which is not the intention.

[image]

--- Update 2:

I was confused - the problem was actually that it synced on downwards pulses too. So that's why I saw partial syncing, the upwards sync was always complete. So I've changed C1 now back to 1nF from 15nF and I have this:

[image]

So it's syncing a tiny bit on downwards sync pulses too and if possible I would like to get rid of that. Should I lower the value of C1 even more? Any tips highly welcome!

Update 3:

I've revisited this schematic again now and tried some things, but I realize I don't really understand how the reset is supposed to function.

First off I realized that my timing caps was order of magnitudes bigger than the ones where I pulled the reset schematic from. I have a range switch and timing caps of either 100nF of 1uF as you can see, while the reset schematic was using a timing cap of just 1nF. Since it seemed the pulse wasn't enough to fully reset my timing cap - it merely moved it in a direction, I figured I would lower R7 and R6 for more current to be able to pass through while the FET is open.

So I also found other schematics without any series resistor at all, simply a JFET that would short the timing cap and while trying out values I got all the way down to 0R for R7. However, this made it so that it always resets to 0. My triangle core here is on TimingReset2 while TimingReset1 sits at GND. Shortening the timing cap via the FET simply sets the waveform to ground, but it doesn't reset the *direction*:

[image] And it doesn't seem that I can make R7 fix this. And I really don't understand how this is supposed to work to be honest.

What I want is to be able to send a pulse to this LFO and then it will reset in a repeatable fashion. Therefore the idea of pulling it up to wither Vcc or Vdd felt like a good one, so I could have a non-random waveform.

This reset circuit, anyone understand how it is *supposed* to work and could help me out?

Comment: I don't understand what you think should be different. The triangle wave starts over on each rising edge of the square wave, which is exactly what I would expect to see. Why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: @DaveTweed Yeah, I noticed that too now :) I _think_ I just messed up with by taking a bad picture, but looking at it now, the first one seems just right. I need to get back to you :) I'm away from the project now and can't check until tomorrow, but I was sure there was the case that it pulled towards the sync (low/high) but not all the way but maybe because of freq change when taking the picture it lookss ok.

Comment: @DaveTweed I realized the source of my confusion - problem was actually quite the opposite, that it syncs a little bit on negative output too... Updating question, hope it's readable top to bottom…

Comment: Since you have a scope, you should be taking a closer look at the waveforms around U1A.

Comment: C4 and C5 are upside down on your schematic

Comment: @Colin yeah, I know. One of hundred errors I did on this schematic. It's fixed on the board though :)